# C# struct in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, struct

I try to do something like this:

```
class Program
    {
        public struct frst
        {
            public short Oversize_FrontInch;
            public short Oversize_RearInch;
            public short Oversize_RightInch;
            public short Oversize_LeftInch;
            public short HeightInch;
        }
        public struct sec
        {
            public short Oversize_FrontInch;
            public short Oversize_RearInch;
            public short Oversize_RightInch;
            public short Oversize_LeftInch;
        }
        public void DoSmth<T>() where T:struct
        { 
            T str = new T();
            str.Oversize_FrontInch = (short)2;

        }
    }
```

but i get "t does not contain a definition for ..." error
is there any way do do this? Important thing: for the sake of rest code it is have to be struct.

Comment: Well, you have constrained `T` to any struct. You could call `DoSmth<ConsoleColor>()` or `DoSmth<int>()` and `T` would be `ConsoleColor` or `int`. They clearly don't have a field or property `Oversize_FrontInch`. Remember: C# is statically typed. The compiler must be able to assess the validity of such a method's member accesses at compile time.

Comment: The only way is to constraint your generic also to an interface that's implemented by both structs. But interfaces cannot contain fields so you should change your fields to properties or add some setter-methods that are defined in the interface. Keep in mind that accessing a struct via interface will box the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be great to understand more what you're trying to achieve with these seemingly unrelated structs but here's a version which compiles and runs and keeps `sec` and `frst` as structs:

```
DoSmth<sec>();
DoSmth<frst>();

void DoSmth<T>() where T: struct, IOversize
{ 
    T str = default;
    str.Oversize_FrontInch = (short)2;
    Console.WriteLine(str.GetType());
}


public interface IOversize 
{
    short Oversize_FrontInch {get; set;}
}

public struct sec: IOversize
{
    public short Oversize_FrontInch {get; set;}
}        

public struct frst: IOversize
{
    public short Oversize_FrontInch {get; set;}
    public short HeightInch {get; set;}
}
```

This prints:

```
sec
frst
```

Comment: @kaarq Note that because generic are used here, and the interface is only used for constraining the generic `T`, there is no boxing

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want something like this.

Struct cannot inherit so you code cannot do what you want.

You can instead use a base class and inherit data class from it.

But be aware that you need to inherit a default constructor in order to create a dataclass in a generic function.

This is a simple example for you to play with, you can edit and polish it as you want.

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public class baseclass{
        public short Oversize_FrontInch;
        public short Oversize_RearInch;
        public short Oversize_RightInch;
        public short Oversize_LeftInch;
    }
    public class frst:baseclass
    {
        public short HeightInch;
    }
    public class sec:baseclass 
    { 
    }
    
    public static void DoSmth<T>() where T:baseclass, new()
    { 
        T str = new T();
        str.Oversize_FrontInch = (short)2;
        Console.WriteLine(str.Oversize_FrontInch);
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        DoSmth<frst>();
    }
}
```

Edit: I saw some people suggesting using interface with struct. It is possible. However, it will box all of your value, create performance issue and create unreadable code. I would not recommanded it.

Comment: Why make this method generic at all?

Comment: @arrowd As the asker wants it. Furthermore, it could be more flexible when you have more data class. It is not very obvious when you have a smaller program but when you are writting an expandable program, you would always want your code to be generic.

Comment: @Ice Why produces using structs less readable code than using classes? From using perspective they're looking exactly the same. The only difference is the parameterless ctor that every struct has but a class not necessarily has. They're handled in different ways  in memory. But for the user they're looking exactly the same. IMHO readability is not an argument against structs.

Comment: @arrowd I disagree with ice's argument that code in expandable code should be generic (at all). If no code takes any advantages of that generic it should be removed. But in that case a new instance of the type represented by that generic is created and to be able to create such instance you need it. Yes you're able to create an instance out of a `Type` instance but in that case you've to check the type at runtime whereas this generic is checked at compile time.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann Yes, You are right. I should not say as generic as possible. It is not correct. But at a maintainence perspective, I would like single inherit data class instead of multiple interface. I am not against struct. It's just that I think data class would be a simpler fit for this issue.